# How to Get More Details of A record Using Table Relations in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, relational-database, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I have a DepartmentsWokplans Model that belongs to only one CoprprateWorkPlan. The CorporateWorkPlan Model has many CorporateStrategicObjectives. Using a DepartmentWorkplanId, I'm able to the CoprporateStatergicObjectives using the code I have shared Below but only the  Ids. My problem is how do I get more details about the CoprporateStatergicObjectives (Eg Description, ETC) which are stored in another table using the Id's that I have?

```
DepartmentWorkPlansModel = DepartmentWorkPlans::findOne($DepartmentWorkPlanId); 

$CorporateObjectives = $DepartmentWorkPlansModel->corporateWorkPlan->corporateStrategicObjectives;

//How Do I get more Details about the CorporateObjectives?
```

**Results I'm getting when I Print_r($CorporateObjectives)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => common\models\CorporateStrategicObjectives Object
        (
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [CorporateObjectiveId] => 1
                    [CorporateWorkPlanId] => 5
                    [StrategicObjectiveId] => 5
                )

            [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [CorporateObjectiveId] => 1
                    [CorporateWorkPlanId] => 5
                    [StrategicObjectiveId] => 5
                )

            [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
            [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
            [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Comment: add relation the the CorporateObjectives model https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data

Comment: I've already Done that, here is how I've done it public function getStrategicObjective()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StrategicObjectives::className(), ['StrategicObjectiveId' => 'StrategicObjectiveId']);
    }

Comment: where are store the data you are looking for  (Eg Description, ETC)  ???  in which model  ..??

Comment: In the StrategicObjectives Model

Comment: then how StrategicObjectives   is related with  CorporateObjectives ?? .. you have some function in your CorporateObjectives  with a hasOne relation with  StrategicObjectives    ??? ..  in you print_r you have the id  but not a relation with StrategicObjectives

Comment: The getStrategicObjective() is the relationship between the 2 tables. From the print_r() I'm only getting the StrategicObjectiveId but I also need the Description there. How do I add it there?